# Appended text not showing in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing

I have a Swing application where I am trying to show informational messages in a dialog. I have created a dialog that has two components, a JScrollPane and a JTextArea. I create the object in the main frame and pass it to the class that will append text to the JTextArea. The initial setText text displays but when I call the append method none of the lines display.

Here is the MessageDialog class...

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MessagesDialog extends JDialog {
    private JScrollPane textScrollPane;
    private JTextArea messageArea;

    public MessagesDialog(JFrame parent) {
        super(parent, "Message Display", false);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 250));

        messageArea = new JTextArea();
        messageArea.setText("This is a test\n");
        messageArea.setRows(100);
        messageArea.setEditable(false);

        textScrollPane = new JScrollPane(messageArea);
        textScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));

        layoutComponents();
    }

    private void layoutComponents() {
        setLayout( new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        // First Row
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.gridheight = 1;

        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 0.05;

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gc.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
        add(textScrollPane, gc);

        pack();
    }

    public void appendMessage(String textLine) {
        this.messageArea.append(textLine + "\n");

        System.out.println("MESSAGE AREA = " + this.messageArea.getText());

        pack();
    }
}
```

The text "This is a test" displays in the window. When the appendMessage method is called nothing is displayed, but the console shows all of the correct lines.

These are the lines of code to create the object...

```
messagesDialog = new MessagesDialog(this);
messagesDialog.setVisible(true);

processZipFile = new ProcessZipFile(messagesDialog);
```

The processZipFile object is the one that calls messageAppend...

```
messagesDialog.appendMessage(String.format("Extracting file %s to %s\n", file, logOutputPath));
```

Why are the appended lines not showing in the JTextArea?

UPDATE: I changed the initial setRows to 100 and removed the one in the messageAppend method. When I removed the setPreferredSize for the scroll pane the scroll pane no longer showed. I instead removed the same from the text and kept the one for the scroll pane, and that restored the scroll pane.

UPDATE #2: After doing more testing the problem isn't that the text area isn't being updated but that it's only repainting after the process is complete. I've tried repaint() but that doesn't make any difference.

Thanks,
Gary

Comment: You start with `setRows(0)`. As the number of rows depends of the number of `\n` in the message, I would use a `JTextPane` and remove all `setRows`. For that purpose  you already have the `JScrollPane`.

Comment: I removed both setRows and it didn't make any difference. I have another dialog that does basically the same thing, but displays lines from a log. I used the same code, including the setRows and it works without a problem. Thanks

Comment: Don't use setRows(0). The point of the number is to allow the text area to determine its preferred size. Use a reasonable value. Then don't use setPreferredSize() on the scroll panel. There is also no need to make individual Swing component visible. That is the default (except for frame and dialogs etc). We don't know the context of how the code is used. Maybe you are blocking the Event Dispatch Thread which prevents the GUI from repainting itself. Otherwise if you have a proper reference to the text area then the text should appear.

Comment: Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.